# AudioQueue play File from certain location.?

Tags: audioqueue

I want to implement AudioSeeking functionality through AudioQueue services.Simply i have a .wav file  of 20 seconds.After playing it once,for next all loops I want it to play from its 5 seconds.Any working solution?